How should I set it up so that GoLand can do breakpoint stepping debugging?
My computer is a Mac M1 laptop
Go version is 1.21.6
GoLand IDE version is 2023.1.5
When I turn on breakpoints and debug mode, I can't stop at my breakpoint settings.
The program will directly execute all the code. How can I set it up to debug each code statement step by step?
I hope to interrupt the execution process through breakpoints and debug each code statement step by step.



I've solved this problem in the following way. (the following directory paths are applicable to Mac OS systems, and on other OS they need to be modified)
1. Install the latest delve
git clone https://github.com/go-delve/delve
cd delve && make install

2. delve will be installed in ~/go/bin/dlv
3. GoLand configuration for dlv

GoLand "Help -> Edit Custom VM Options"
-Ddlv.path=/Users/#your path#/go/bin/dlv


GoLand "Help -> Edit Custom properties":
dlv.path=/Users/#your path#/go/bin/dlv



4. Restart GoLand
My GoLand IDE started to stop on breakpoints after I have applied the aforementioned changes.

